Why does 写真に収めとこ mean take a picture? And what is the purpose of とこ in this case?
Scenario: A group of friends are heading to the beach for summer vacation. One of them is asleep on the train and someone says:

よし　写真に収めとこぜ

The official translation is:

Let's take a picture!

I'm curious why 収める is used. Looking up its definition, I can't wrap my head around how and why it's being used in this sentence. I usually see 写真を撮る so this usage is new to me. I'm also not sure what the purpose of とこ is in this case? I know it is a contraction of ところ and from what I've learned so far, it can mean place or just about to do-. But I can't find any resource specifically for this case verb stem + ところ.

Edit: As Karl pointed out below, to capture on film is explicitly stated in the definition and I've missed it! I was probably too tired from my immersion session when I wrote this question 

"Looking up its definition, I can't wrap my head around how and why it's being used in this sentence." - ??? The meaning "to capture (on film)" is explicitly listed there.

It's not a form of “ところ” here, it would be if it were “収めるとこ. In this case however it's a contraction of “収めておこう” which is the volitional form of “収めておく” as in “to do for later use”. In fact, looking at the picture it says “収めとこう” but the “う” is often omitted as well in this contraction. Though in my experience not as often when putting “〜ぜ” behind it.
“収める” can mean  “to store” or “to put into”. As in “to store it in a picture”, so we arrive at the full translation of “'Kay, let's take a picture mate.” or something like that.
